# Python 3.8 converts all strings to variables upon writing to file

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to write a script that can grab the MAC Address of the computer that runs it with the `arp` command. Currently, I'm using:

```
with open('mac.txt', 'w') as mac:
    print(str(os.system('arp -a')
```

However, it keeps becoming a single integer, displaying nothing but "0".

How would I keep the MAC address as a string?

Comment: `os.system` returns an `int` always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.system` runs the command and returns an `int`, probably the exit code or something. Please read about it to know exactly what it returns.

If you want the output of the command, use,

```
os.popen('arp -a').read()
```

Change your code to

```
with open('mac.txt', 'w') as mac:
    print(os.popen('arp -a').read())
```